# Detect alternating key events

Tags: javascript, keyevent, dom-events

I'm writing a script for the following task:

The task is for participants to alternately press the <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> keys on the keyboard as quickly as possible for 10 minutes. Every time a participant successfully press the <kbd>a</kbd> key followed by the <kbd>b</kbd> key, they should receive a point. Points should only be awarded for alternating key presses, pressing the <kbd>a</kbd> key or the <kbd>b</kbd> key without alternating between the two should not result in points.

The part of the problem I am asking about is the detection of alternating key events. I attempted this myself and ended up with the code below, but it does not achieve the desired result and I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

... but I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

How can I fix my code and achieve the desired result?

```js
var points = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    var x = event.code;
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (x == 'KeyA' && event.code == 'KeyB') {
        points = points + 1;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
    }
});
```

```html
<p>Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one event listener, and you need to define the <kbd>a</kbd> key press state variable (`x`) outside of the listener function so that it can be referenced by subsequent executions of the listener function.

You also need to make sure that you reset the <kbd>a</kbd> key press variable after the <kbd>b</kbd> key press.

it is also generally a good idea to cache your references to elements, rather than selecting the element from the DOM each time your listener function runs, and using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` bypasses the HTML parser.

```js
const target = document.getElementById('points');
var points = 0, x;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.key === 'a') x = true; // If this is an `a` key event, set x to true
    if(event.key === 'b') {
        // if this is a `b` key event and a was not pressed, return early
        if(!x) return; 
        // otherwise increment the points variable and assign the result to 
        // the textContent property of the target element
        target.textContent = ++points; 
        // remember to set x to false again
        x = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<p>Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
```